Sequelize transaction rollback not working
I am creating a project using express.js where I want to group one or more database queries performed using sequelze.js and PostgreSQL to create a transaction. I have created managed transaction using sequelize, When one of the query failed subsequent queries didn't perform but the query before that got committed. The console has logged rollback, but rollback didn't work.
Is this the usual transaction behavior in sequelize? Is there any configuration to be done to allow rollback? Please find the code below
async function(req){
//some code
try{
const result = await db.sequelize.transaction(async(t)=>{
await Manager.create({
//user data
}, {transaction:t}
)
await Project.create({
//user_secret data
}, {transaction:t})

await Team.create({
//employer data
}, {transaction:t})

//code to generate token based on query data
//return token
});
return result
}catch((err)=>{
console.log("error while performing transaction: "+err);
return err;
}
}

I would like to add that these tables are not related by any relation.
I want all queries to be rolled back, if any operation in transaction block fails. But using this code structure Manager is inserted in DB, even though project insertion failed because of sequelizeerror.


When one of the query failed subsequent queries didn't perform but the query before that got committed.

It is not an issue of the transaction but the issue of the error/exception handling which is thrown by the callback you passed to the transaction(async(t)=>....).
In your case the even though error/exception(failed query) has been thrown but it not catched properly so does rollback operation is not executed. Because along with catch() block you passed an arrow function which is syntactically incorrect.
For more information you can see MDN docs for try{}..catch(){}
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch
By default catch() block get the error-object (in your case failed query report) if callback throws error and only then transaction gets rolled back as per the documentation of sequelize.
For more information you can have look into the docs...
https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/transactions/#managed-transactions
Keep the catch-block intact as per Syntax .But if you want to define a arrow function for error-log.You can do this.
..}catch(err){
  const error = (err) => {
            console.log("Error while performing transaction: " + error);
            throw error; // Re-throw the error to ensure it's handled properly elsewhere
        };
        
        error(err);
}

It will resolve the issue.
